# onClick wait for sound to finish before playing the next click

Tags: java, android

I am working on a small project and I need a sound to be played when a user presses a button. That part I seem to have gotten down. But the problem is that if the user spams the button the sound will play over and over, overlapping itself. How do I lock out the button during the duration of the sound playing, or maybe put each click into a queue to play on after the other, and not at the instant of press? This is what I have so far. I'm a bit of a noob to android development. Thanks.

```java
public void SOS(View v) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sos);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.stop();
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: after button press check if music is playing, if it is then either restart it or ignore button press.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a jbutton? If so then just use. Replace  with the name of your JButton.

```
//Disables it.
<JbuttonName>.setEnabled(false);

//Enables it
<JbuttonName>.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Since this is Android, it's most likely not going to use swing.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to your mediaplayer instead of creating it each time, then play it only if it isn't already playing, like this:

```
if(!mp.isPlaying())
{
     mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
MediaPlayer mp;

public void mpStart() {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sos);
    mp.start(); 
}

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
        });
```